# component is not detecting in slot with new instantiation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

application in Qt 5.2.1. here is interface :-

[image]

Here is goto cell dialog header file :-

```
#ifndef GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
#define GOTOCELLDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class gotocellDialog;
}

class gotocellDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit gotocellDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
~gotocellDialog();

private slots:
void on_lineEditCellLocation_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

private:
    Ui::gotocellDialog *ui;
};

#endif // GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
```

and here is gotocell.cpp

```
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"

gotocellDialog::gotocellDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::gotocellDialog)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

     ui->pushButtonOK->setEnabled(false);
     QRegExp regexp("[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]{0,2}");
     ui->lineEditCellLocation->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regexp, this));

 }

 gotocellDialog::~gotocellDialog()
 {
    delete ui;
 }

 void gotocellDialog::on_lineEditCellLocation_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
 {ui->pushButtonOK->setEnabled(ui->lineEditCellLocation->hasAcceptableInput());
 }
```

here another file mainwindow creating new gotocell object but unable  to access its(gotocell's) component lineEditCellLocation

```
void spMainWindow::gotocell()
{
     gotocelldlg = new gotocellDialog(this);
     if(gotocelldlg->exec())
     {
          QString str = gotocelldlg->lineEditCellLocation->text.toUpper();
    spsheet->setCurrentCell(str.mid(1).toInt() - 1,
                                      str[0].unicode() - 'A');
     }
 }
```

here error is showing as :-

```
/opt/project/Qt/spreadsheet/spmainwindow.cpp:81: error: 'class  gotocellDialog' has no member named 'lineEditCellLocation'
 /opt/project/Qt/spreadsheet/spmainwindow.cpp:-1: In member function 'void spMainWindow::sort()':
```

here i want to access gotocelldialog's lineEditCellLocation but unable to get access.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this is just a small typo:

Replace the following line

```
QString str = gotocelldlg->lineEditCellLocation->text.toUpper();
```

with

```
QString str = ui->lineEditCellLocation->text.toUpper();
```

For your next posts you should include a minimal reproducible examples. This also includes the post of your ui file. Otherwise, it is very difficult for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: actually gotocelldialog in composition of spMainwindow i declared it  as gotocellDoalog * gotocelldlg; in spMainWindow class. and as you said

Answer (score 0):

finally i got its solution i did like this :-\

```
 gotocelldlg = new gotocellDialog(this);
  if(gotocelldlg->exec())
  {
    QLineEdit *ledit = findChild<QLineEdit*>("lineEditCellLocation");

    QString str = ledit->text().toUpper();

    spsheet->setCurrentCell(str.mid(1).toInt() - 1,
                                      str[0].unicode() - 'A');
}
```

Comment: Proper way to do it is to emit signal form `gotocellDialog` (note you are violating name coding conventions). Then connecting this singal to respective slot.